# Angular mudulo is not defined

Tags: angularjs, syntax-error

Sou novo em programação, porem estou estudando.

Estou me deparando com o seguinte problema no angular:

> WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once, ReferenceError: ponto is not defined.

Comment: Se pudesse disponibilizar um pouco do código para que nós pudessemos ajudar, ia ser um belo passo para a solução do seu problema. [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)